# sbt works fine on Windows with play 2.2.1, but gives compilation errors on CentOS

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

After having found a bug in Cloudhopper library we decided to migrate our project to Play Framework `2.2.1`. On Windows the migration went fine and the project compiles and runs on Java 6 and 7.

When I deployed the project to a CentOS machine, with OpenJDK 7.0, I faced `Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0`:

```
ERROR in /home/yaron/backup-manager-arseny/app/com/tjat/constants/ErrorConstants.java         (at line 6)[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m   UnableToCreateDirectory("Could not create directory on   disk"), 
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m   FileNotFound("The specific file was not found"), [0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m   UnableToReadFile("The file could not be loaded from disk"), 
[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mSyntax error on tokens, delete these tokens[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m   public List<Contact> getContactList(Long page, int      contactsPerPage);[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m               ^^^^^^^[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mSyntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m210 problems (210 errors)[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m(compile:[31mcompile[0m) javac returned nonzero exit code[0m
```

To fix this, I added the following `javacOptions` to `Build.scala`:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "5.0")
```

but then another error showed up:

```
[error]  ERROR in /home/yaron/backup-manager-arseny/app/com/tjat/backupmanager/BackupManagerImpl.java (at line 37)
[error]         public String retrieveContacts(String userId, String backupId, String    fromId, String toId) throws ApiException {
[error]                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error] The method retrieveContacts(String, String, String, String) of type BackupManagerImpl must override a superclass method
```

There is no problem compiling the project in Eclipse on Windows on the other machine.

What might be the cause of the issue? Please advice.

Comment: What has changed that the errors were `[0m[[31merror[0m]` and then became just `[error]`? What's the output of `sbt about`? How do you start sbt? What's the sbt startup script? See [HowTo Install Java on CentOS 4 and CentOS 5](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaOnCentOS).

Comment: the [0m[[31merror[0m] are probably just copy paste fragmentions
all the rest is as default

Comment: What about the other questions? `sbt about`? What about `java -version`? What about the startup script of sbt? That should lead to an answer.

Comment: java -- version returns java version "1.7.0_45" OpenJDK Runtime Environment 

we launch sbt via play and it is 0.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Mark Harrah's answer on the a now defunct mailing list of sbt](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/XIK5Ohlmdro/HrRjTgToo6YJ):

> You can control the version of Java used with`javaHome`:
>
> ```
> javaHome := Some(file("/path/to/java/home"))
> ```
>
> If you put this in`~/.sbt/global.sbt`, it should take effect for all of
>   your projects and plugins built on your machine without having to
>   publish it as part of your build (where it won't work for others).

Use `javaHome` setting to query the value while in your project (or any other directory to see its global configuration).

```
$ sbt --warn 'help javaHome'
Selects the Java installation used for compiling and forking.  If None, uses the Java installation running the build.

$ sbt --warn info 'show javaHome'
[info] None
```

When the `javaHome` setting's not set up (`None` is the result as shown above), the default JVM on the system's used.

Check also the shell script that launches sbt how the JVM is set up. See [Manual Installation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#manual-installation) in sbt's official documentation for more guidance.

Comment: yes indeed our javac version was 1.6
after upgrading to 1.7 problem was solved..
thank you